# How to prevent /* from creating a comment block?

Tags: c++, comments

I'm trying to print out the following:

```
cout << *pointer1/*pointer2 << endl;
```

However, because `/*` opens a comment block, everything past `/*` is treated as a comment. The solution I've come up so far is this:

```
int tempPointer = *pointer;
cout << *pointer1/tempPointer << endl;
```

This works but isn't very elegant.

Is there a way to prevent `/*` from creating a comment block in this instance?

Comment: `cout << *pointer1 << "/" << *pointer2 << endl;`

Comment: Just leave a space between slash and star: `*pointer1 / *pointer2`

Comment: Whitespace. Use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add a space or put the pointer dereference in brackets. (This also improves readability.)

```
cout << *pointer1 / *pointer2 << endl;
```

or

```
cout << *pointer1/(*pointer2) << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

Put parentheses around the expression:

```
(*pointer2)
```